# Passing Pointer from function to function

Tags: c, pointers

I'm a bit new to understanding pointers so I was hoping someone could check this to help me make sure I've got the right idea on how pointers work. I'm trying to simplify the idea of what a pointer is and how to use them

```
functA(int *numb){

functB(numb);

}

functB(int *numb){

functC(numb);

}

functC(int *numb){

*numb+=1;

}

int main (){

int testNumber = 0;

functA(&testNumber);
.
.
.
}
```

So in main, I'm sending the address of testNumber to funct A. So when I send this address to functA, there is no problem, correct?

Since funct A has a pointer parameter, which can hold an address, it won't run into a problem when I send an address, right? Then, since numb (in functA) is a pointer, I can send it to an functB because functB can accept an address. Also, I'm still sending the same address that testNumber is in, correct?

Again, I send numb (from functB) to functC and in functC, I'm derefencing this location (is there a better way to say this?) and increasing the count by 1. So when this is done, testNumber should be 1, correct?

I know this might sound silly and all, but I'm just trying to grasp this conceptually. I spent more time than I'm willing to admit trying to get this down concept on a project I just submitted (I did it, but it took way too long)

Comment: It seems that your code for changing `testNumber` by means of pointer is working, and value of `testNumber` should be 1 after `functA(&testNumber)` call if you add `;` at the end of that line

Comment: Pointers are always tricky for new C programmers. Just remember that with the * beside it, it's the value, without it, it's the address. When you pass a pointer to another function, and you want to pass the _address_, pass the variable name without a star. The receiving function's variable must have a star. The reverse is true when passing a value (unless you want the receiving function to also be a pointer). There are exceptions to these rules, but I highly doubt you will need to worry about them unless you're rewriting memcpy or something ;)

Comment: @VolAnd ah thank you for that. I'll fix it right now

Comment: Nitpick: `derefencing` -> `dereferencing`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A variable is stored at a location in memory and has a value stored in it. Every location has address.

`variable`

`location_value`

`location_address`

A pointer (say, `int *p`) is simply a variable like other variables(say, `int a;`). Difference is a pointer stores address of some location (which you already know).

`variable: int testNumber = 10;`

`location_value: 10`

`location_address: 0xABCD000  // <-- 'testNumber' is stored at this location`

`----------------------------`

`variable: int *numb = &testNumber;`

`location_value: 0xABCD000   // <-- note: value of 'numb' is an address, address of 'testNumber'`

`location_address: 0x1234000 // <-- numb itself is stored at 0x12340000`

Since, `numb` is a variable you can go on assigning its value to other variable of same type.

In your case `functC::numb = functB::numb = functA::numb = &testNumber = 0xABCD000`. which is correct.

So, when you dereference  `*functC::numb` you are accessing the variable which is stored at address `functC::numb`, which happens to be `testNumber`. So `testNumber` gets incremented when you did `*functC::numb += 1;`

Answer (score 2):

Way too many question in this post. As long as you're deferencing *correct* address, you'll be happy. But too much pointers here and there likely is going to cause some bugs, be careful about it.

> So when I send this address to functA, there is no problem, correct?

Yes

> Since funct A has a pointer parameter, which can hold an address, it
>   won't run into a problem when I send an address, right?

Yes

> Also, I'm still sending the same address that testNumber is in,
>   correct?

Yes

> .....is there a better way to say this?)

No and Yes, it depends on requirement.

> So when this is done, testNumber should be 1, correct?

Yes

Comment: Could you elaborate this part `No and Yes, it depends on requirement` ?

Comment: @4386427 I would, if I could, but I can't. There is more than one way to skin a cat. May be other way is more logical/readable, but IMO we can't tell given the current OP's post.